# How can I decide is there a specific text in web site withSelenium

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webclient

**EDITED POST**

First of all, there is a similar question on site but it did not work that's why I am asking.
I should decide is there a specific text `LİSTELENECEK VERİ BULUNAMAMIŞTIR.` on HTML code, there are only `id` attribute here is the HTML code:

```html
<center id="genelUyariCenterTag">LİSTELENECEK VERİ BULUNAMAMIŞTIR.</center>
```

Here is the C# code:

```cs
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
void goMadde15Down() {
                    driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("İŞVEREN")).Click();
                    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                    driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("TEŞVİKLER VE TANIMLAR")).Click();
                    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                    driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("4447/GEÇİCİ 15. MADDE LİSTELEME/SİLME")).Click();
                    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                    string siteSource15 = client.DownloadString("https://uyg.sgk.gov.tr/IsverenSistemi");

                    string strText = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//center[@id='genelUyariCenterTag' and contains(.,'BULUNAMAMIŞTIR')]")).Text;

                    if (strText.Contains("LİSTELENECEK VERİ BULUNAMAMIŞTIR."))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("madde15 there is no Excel");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("madde 15 there is an Excel");
                    }
```

The problem is, the condition always converge to `else` clause

Comment: why don't you use selenium `webdriver` to verify the text of `webelement`? Have you tried anything like?

Comment: Actually I am a very beginner on Visual Studio and C# can you please give an example. From now on I click the buttons or filling the forms from the database using Selenium.

Comment: Hello, @hasanhüseyin I understand your free texts in HTML and we are talking the same language are you trying to download an excel file if it exists else if go next page?

Comment: Yes, it is what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `if` and `else` If you can use `try-catch`  blocks you can use following code:

```cs
 void goMadde15Down() {
       driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("İŞVEREN")).Click();
       driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
       driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("TEŞVİKLER VE TANIMLAR")).Click();
       driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
       driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("4447/GEÇİCİ 15. MADDE LİSTELEME/SİLME")).Click();
       driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

            try  {
                    Console.WriteLine("There is an Excel File");
                    //Download code here


                 }
            catch (Exception e)
                 {
                        Console.WriteLine("There is no Excel File");
                 }
```

Also `try catch` block is more efficient then `if` and `else`

Answer (score 0):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `ElementExists` and use below xpath.

You need to install `SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers` pakage from `Manage Nuget Packages`.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
string strText=wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//center[@id='genelUyariCenterTag' and contains(.,'BULUNAMAMIŞTIR')]"))).Text;
    if (strText.Contains("LİSTELENECEK VERİ BULUNAMAMIŞTIR."))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("madde15 there is no Excel");
            }
     else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("madde 15 there is an Excel");
             }
```

---

Try updated one without `WebDriverWait`

```
string strText=driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//center[@id='genelUyariCenterTag' and contains(.,'BULUNAMAMIŞTIR')]")).Text;

            if (strText.Contains("LİSTELENECEK VERİ BULUNAMAMIŞTIR."))
                {
                Console.WriteLine("madde15 there is no Excel");
                }
                else
                {
                Console.WriteLine("madde 15 there is an Excel");
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but when I am trying to install `SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers`  It warn me like `Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Selenium.WebDriver 3.141.0' is not compatible with 'SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers 1.0.0 constraint: Selenium.WebDriver (>= 4.0.0-alpha04)'.    
 `    
 I am using version 3.141.0 when I check version updates 3.141.0 is already the most up to date version.

Comment: @hasanhüseyin : Try without `WebDriverWait` check my answer.

Comment: Now on `string strText = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//center[@id='genelUyariCenterTag' and contains(.,'BULUNAMAMIŞTIR')]")).Text; ` I get error says `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'Failed to convert data to an object'`

Comment: Can you post your updated code on your original post to check where it went wrong.This should work.

Comment: @hasanhüseyin : can you mention step to reach that text.I can't find when see the url and i believe you have  define the web driver with browser either chrome or FF or IE.